# problem with sql function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a procedure that would return a table with 'child numbers' of a given 8-digit number form database. For instance, a child of a number 54000000 would be 54100000, 54009900 54000001 and so on.

My idea is to declare a variable table (ParentPartTable) that would contain just the 'parent' part of a number (table, not a single value because we can pass more than one number whose childs we need) so in example above it would contain '54' and then do something like:

```
INSERT INTO @ReturnTable
SELECT n.Symbol, n.Id
FROM NumbersTable n
JOIN @ParentPartTable p
ON n.Symbol LIKE p.SYMBOL + '%';
```

Unfortunately this doesnt seem to work. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: If your data is as you think that should work. I'm pretty sure I've used a technique like this before.

Comment: What's the datatype of `n.Symbol` ?

Comment: i declare it as NCHAR(8)

Comment: Declare it as `nvarchar(8)` (if you need Unicode `varchar(8)` otherwise). Your symbol will be padded to 8 chars so your `LIKE` will be `LIKE '54______%'` (Had to use underscore to represent contiguous spaces as they get collapsed in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
DECLARE @ParentPartTable TABLE
(
SYMBOL VARCHAR(8) /*Don't use CHAR(8) here!*/
)

INSERT INTO @ParentPartTable VALUES ('54');

WITH NumbersTable AS
(
SELECT '54000000' AS Symbol, 1 AS Id
)

SELECT n.Symbol, n.Id
FROM NumbersTable n
JOIN @ParentPartTable p
ON n.Symbol LIKE p.SYMBOL + '%';
```

Are you sure you aren't using `char(8)`? As that would pad trailing spaces.

Comment: yes, i used nchar which apparently does the same thing, thanks

Comment: @matt99 - In your table variable? In that case the answer you accepted won't resolve your issue! Casting from `nchar` to `varchar` won't remove the trailing spaces that were causing the problem.

Comment: at first i changed the type of table variable to nvarchar and it still did not work, i changed it to varchar and used the casting pavel proposed at once.If i understand you, when i saved the query as utf-8 formatted i should avoid nvarchar so actually changing the variable type to varchar could be enough (looks like it is since i removed casting and it still works)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **Symbol** is numeric in both tables, you need to cast ti to varchar in the LIKE clausule.
`ON n.Symbol LIKE cast(p.SYMBOL as varchar) + '%';` should work.

Comment: this works indeed, thank you. you're right that the problem was with the type of this field